# what is the best way to toggle two divs in the same area

Tags: jquery, html

i am loading two divs in a page: divA and divB

i have divB display style = none.

I have a link that says "Show viewB".  When i click this i want div B to show up where divA is and divA to hide.

i then want the link to change to "Show viewA"

what is the most elegant way of doing this in jquery?

Comment: @bemace: Why the jquery-ui-tabs tag ? Since the OP needs a *single* link to toggle the visibility of two elements, it kind of rules out jquery-ui-tabs by definition.

Comment: @Freek - guess you're right.  Rolled back

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using the `toggle()` function:

```
$("#link").toggle(function() {
  toggleDivs();
  $(this).html("Show viewA");
}, function() {
  toggleDivs();
  $(this).html("Show viewB");
});

function toggleDivs() {
  $("#divA, #divB").toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Zmsnd/

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#container > .toggleMe').toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i,txt) { return txt === "Show viewB" ? "Show viewA" : "Show viewB"; });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my second try that I think that's more elegant than my original answer:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#divA, #divB").toggle();
  $(this).text(function(i, text) { return (text == "Show viewA") ? "Show viewB" : "Show viewA" });
});
```

Comment: This one is incorrect. Inside the `.click()` handler, you're *assigning* additional click events every time you click the link.

Comment: You are right, inside the `click` event, `toggle` could not be used. Updated now.

Comment: Didn't noticed ;D Then I should +1 for your answer~

Answer (score 1):

That's not very hard, try something like this:

```
var $divA = $('#a'),
    $divB = $('#b'),
    $link = $('#link');

// Initialize everything
$link.text( 'Show A' );
$divA.hide();

$link.click(function(){

  // If A is visible when the link is clicked
  // you need to hide A and show B
  if( $divA.is( ':visible' ) ){
    $link.text( 'Show A' );
    $divA.hide();
    $divB.show();
  } else {
    $link.text( 'Show B' );
    $divA.show();
    $divB.hide();
  }

  return false;
});
```

[**Example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QAxgD/)

Comment: That solution is straightforward, but is it elegant?

Answer (score 0):

```
var divA = $("#divA");
var divB = $("#divB");
var originalState = true;

$("#toggler").click(function(e) {
    originalState = !originalState;
    if (originalState) {
        divB.hide();
        divA.show();
    } else {
        divA.hide();
        divB.show();
    }
    $(this).html(originalState ? "Show viewB" : "Show viewA");
    e.preventDefault(); // Assuming you're using an anchor and "#" for the href
});
```

Comment: error logic~ when originalState is true,then divA.show() and divB.hide().

Comment: Yep, was all screwed up, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers don't give you the effect that you desire, you might want to try using the [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method instead (i.e., `target.replaceWith(newContent)`). As the name suggests, it will replace the `target` with the `newContent`. The best part is that it will do it in-place.

```
divA.replaceWith(divB);
...
divB.replaceWith(divA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
$("#link").click(function() {
    $("div[id^=tog_]").toggle();
    $(this).text("Show " + $("div[id^=tog_]").not(":visible").attr("id").substr(4));
});
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvgbg/).

Hope this helps.